# Ajaxmessaging rails gem - replacement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I found this gem:
http://code.google.com/p/ajaxmessaging/

Because this project is inactive I need something more fresh to do the same stuff, in my case, notification messaging to the client.

There is something similar and better than this? (for Passenger)

Comment: Have you looked at http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at Pusher (http://pusher.com), Faye (http://faye.jcoglan.com, http://asciicasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye), or Juggernaut (https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut).  Pusher is probably easiest to get started with, but its a commercial product after a certain level of usage.